# How do I connect to a collection in a database on AtlasDB with multiple databases on one server

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I want to be able to connect to a database on AtlasDB using mongoose, but I'm so new I don't really know what I'm doing.

I've previously built a database with multiple collections on AtlasDB, but I now have a pre-built group of databases on a server and I can't figure out how to connect to the server and then one specific database and pull collections in.

Previously I've built the schemas and populated the collections using those, but I don't really know what to do with a pre-existing set of databases.

Right now this is all the code I have:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app     = express(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
    async = require("async"),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect("mongoDBURI", {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Right now all I'd like to do is connect, do a find and return all docs from a collection in a database called sample_airbnb with a collection called listingsAndReviews. Any help, or just pointing me in the direction of some good tutorials would be immensely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: maybe this help? https://developerhandbook.com/mongodb/connect-mongo-atlas-mongoose/

Comment: No, I got error with "MongoError: user is not allowed to do action [find] on [admin.sample_airbnb]"

Comment: @WeijingJayLin, You need to add "admin permission"s to be able to query the db. This will be under "security" tab then "Database Access". "Add new user" button (which is then used in your connection string).